# Distribute App with previous version of XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

Given that iOS9 & XCode7 are officially released, is it possible to submit an app for Apple review using a previous version of XCode (eg. XCode 6.1)?

If the answer is affirmative, will the app submitted through XCode 6.1 be able to be downloaded by iOS9 device (provided that the deployment target set to 5.1.1)?

Platform in use:

- iMac 21.5-inch, Late 2009
- Mac OSX 10.9.5
- XCode version 6.1

Comment: NEVER use old version of Xcode to release App. Always use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Apple hasn't asked developers to refrain from submitting apps from old versions of Xcode yet. So, you will be able to submit you app from Xcode 6.1. And it will run in iOS 9 devices. But, it's not the ideal way to handle the app submission. There could be some bugs when the app is run in iOS 9 devices. It is advisable to verify the app in the latest Xcode version and submit from there.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment App Store Team requires that to publish your application must be compliant with iOS8 and 64bit architecture (so Xcode6.x better last Xcode 6.4). 
The deadline for iOS9 would be probably February for new app and July for updates.